# Android: Fail to connect to camera service at Camera.open();

Tags: android, android-camera

There are many questions similar to this, but none helped me:

my manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.cameraapi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraAPIActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my Activity class is:

```
public class CameraAPIActivity extends Activity {
    private Camera myCamera = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (checkCameraHardware(this)) {

            try {

                myCamera = Camera.open();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                //Here i get the Exception:  Failed to connect to camera service
            }
        }
}

private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
```

i get the Exception at the line

```
myCamera = Camera.open();
```

Thank You

Comment: Are you trying this on Emulator or device?

Comment: Can you please paste the log output?

Comment: i am trying this on a Device. I am getting checkCameraHardware value as true.

Comment: @ss1271 Its just the single line "java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service"

Comment: Fantastic! Code from developer site is not working!!!

Comment: :-| Actually the problem is the code works for the 1st time. If i relaunch the app again then it crashed giving this error. Even the Camera launched from Home Screen doesn't work. This might be because i didn't use myCamera.release(); in my code??

Comment: yes. Use the `release` in your app.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc buddy please accept the correct answer, that might help the other people who r having the same issue. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Forgot to add

```
myCamera.release();
```

in my code. hence it works for the first time i launch the application. When i re-launch it the Camera service is not available.

Comment: Here are some pointers to handle the camera properly : http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

Comment: I added this piece of code in onResume() method works like a charm

Comment: before using Camera.open(id);  do this if(camer!=null){  camera.release()}

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the following

```
private Preview mPreview;      // Global variable
mPreview = new Preview(this);  // onCreate()
setContentView(mPreview);      // onCreate()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You imported the wrong camera class at the top of your source file (I sink that), which is `android.graphics.Camera`.

You need `android.hardware.Camera` instead.

After:

```
myCamera = Camera.open(); - start working.
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want to take a pic from camera use

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);`
```

also add this function

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

imageView is the View where you may want to set that captured image.

Comment: But i want to use Camera API instead of Intent